# IE10 file url issue

Tags: url, cross-browser, versioning, internet-explorer-10

I'm developing a web-page which should support IE10. My users should be able to download an installation file (.exe) but I will update this file so that it'll have versions. Suppose the file name is **file.exe** but the link to the file is like

```
<url>/file.exe?v1.1.21.0
```

Here, other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, ie8, ie9) download the file nicely but ie10 downloads it as **file.0** (probably because of the question mark in the url). After download, when I rename it as **file.exe** it works nicely as exe file but of course I cannot expect it from the users. I also don't want to remove the version number from the url because then, it might download an old file remaining in the cache etc. Is there a workaround for this, to download the file with the proper name?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a `Content-Disposition` header containing the correct filename.

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.exe`

In case you are running an Apache server, have a look at this: https://serverfault.com/questions/101948/how-to-send-content-disposition-headers-in-apache-for-files

**Update**

Here's an example `.htaccess`:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/(file\.exe)$" FILENAME=$1
Header set "Content-disposition" "attachment; filename=%{FILENAME}e" env=FILENAME
UnsetEnv FILENAME
```

It will add the `Content-Disposition` header only in case the request URI is `/file.exe` (change this to your needs), so it can be safely added in case there are other files in the directory that shouldn't be affected.

Comment: From what I understand, this forces the browser to pop-up a "Save As" window to save the file. However currently, even if I select the "Save As" option while downloading the file, it doesn't download correctly. By default it sees file name as **file** and type as **0 file** (because of ".0" in the end, coming from version number). Even if I change the tpye as "All Files" (that's the only other option) it still downloads as **file.0**.

Comment: It cannot force the browser to anything at all, it just tells it what it's about to receive, how the browser handles the data is totally up to the browser. However, the intention of the `attachment` `Content-Disposition` is of course to make the browser handle the data as a download, instead of inline data, and the additional `filename` parameter is the suggested filename, of course it's again up to the browser what it's doing with this information, however mostly all browsers respect the header and use it over the filename in the URL, and so does IE10. So give it a try, it works just fine.